# Complex series: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( z^{n-2}/5^{n+1}\right)$ for $0 < |z| < 5$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How would one compute
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{n-2}}{5^{n+1}}
$$
where $0\lt|z|\lt5$?

I have literally no idea where to start, all I know is that the answer will not have summations. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know that for $|w|<1$ we have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty w^n=\frac{1}{1-w}$?

Comment: @DennisGulko yes and I can potentially see a use for that here! Would I use a substitution?

Comment: Yep. That's precisely it. You don't have to consider it a substitution; but, if it helps you understand the manipulation, then go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said above,

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty {z^{n-2}\over 5^{n+1}}= {1\over 5z^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left({z\over 5}\right)^n.
$$

To solve this, it may aid you to make the substitution $u=\frac{z}{5}$. Then,
$$
{1\over 5z^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left({z\over 5}\right)^n=\frac{1}{5z^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u^n.
$$

The sum is geometric in $u$; thus, you apply the [geometric series formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Comment: Okay thank you, this is brilliant. So it's rather simple after all. All I do now is substitute back my z/5 and I'll have my answer. And I'm guessing the reason 0 < z < 5 is something to do with the 5 on the bottom, so I can have up to 5 on the top so it's less than 1 overall.

Comment: Oh, yeah. The range $0<|z|<5$ implies $0<|u|<1$, which satisfies the condition of a geometric series converging to a finite value. If you'd like, feel free to click the little checkmark and vote this answer up. I'd like to hit 1k tonight. :P

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {z^{n-2}\over 5^{n+1}}= {1\over 5z^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left({z\over 5}\right)^n$$

Does this make it a bit more palatable?

Comment: Thank you, can you possibly explain what it means by calculate a series, I've never come across it before. I'm guessing I'll transfer z into x + iy and get the answer in x and y's.

Comment: Becky, you  need to learn about geometric series.  Begin here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: Oh! I know this is a geometric series and I know a bit about them, but I've never seen a question like this before where it's use the words calculate! So, could I substitute x and y's for z and use the limit of the standard geometric series 1/1-x?

Comment: @Becky : you really don't need to go back in terms of $z = x+ iy$. An answer in terms of $z$ is perfectly suitable. If you want to actually "compute the number, given say $z = 1 + i$", then find the "nice-looking expression not involving series" for $z$, then substitute in and make the computations.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\frac{z^{n-2}}{5^{n+1}}=\frac1{5z^2}\left(\frac{z}5\right)^n$$

Comment: Thank you, can you possibly explain what it means by calculate a series, I've never come across it before. I'm guessing I'll transfer z into x + iy and get the answer in x and y's.

Comment: @Becky: No need: just sum the geometric series $$\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac{z}5\right)^n$$ and multiply by $\dfrac1{5z^2}$, and you’re done.

Comment: I got 1/(5z^2 - z^3) correct?

Comment: @Becky: Yes, that looks fine.